# How to "refresh" (re-render) button when text change while using FontAwesome?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following UI:

[image]

and from there I need to change dynamically the button `Archive` and `Unarchive` as well as the icon from FontAwesome depending on the action taken and the response from the backend. The response basically looks like:

```
{"row_id":"12518","status":true}
```

In a few words:

- In the blue row (archived item): if I click on `Unarchive` button and the response is `true` I should: remove the background color, change the button text to `Archive`, change the button class from `unarchive-form` to `archive-form` and change the FontAwesome icon class from `fa fa-arrow-circle-up` to `fa fa-arrow-circle-down`.
- In the other row (non archived item): if I click on `Archive` and the response is `true` then I should: add the blue background, change the button text to `Unarchive`, change the button class from `archive-form` to `unarchive-form` and change the FontAwesome icon class from `fa fa-arrow-circle-down` to `fa fa-arrow-circle-up`.

I have almost everything covered (and I will show the sources for just one case since it's pretty much the same and I don't want to make a big post):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/forms/archive',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        form_id: ids
    }
}).done(function (response) {
    $.each(response, function (index, value) {
        var this_row_tr = $('input[data-form=' + value.row_id + ']').closest('tr'),
            this_btn = this_row_tr.find('.archive-form');

        if (value.status === true) {
            // here I add the background color to the TR 
            this_row_tr.addClass('info');
            // here I swap the button class 
            this_btn.removeClass('archive-form').addClass('unarchive-form');
            // here I swap the button text and also the whole FontAwesome part
            this_btn.text('<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Unarchive');
        } else if (value.status === false) {
            this_row_tr.addClass('error');
            all_archived = false;
        }
    });

    if (all_archived) {
        toastr["success"]("The forms were archived successfully.", "Information");
    } else {
        toastr["error"]("Something went wrong, the forms could not be archived.", "Error");
    }
}).error(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    toastr["error"]("Something went wrong, the forms could not be archived.", "Error");
});
```

But the problem comes when I change the text for the FontAwesome since I get the plain text instead of the icon. For example clicking on `Unarchive` in the first row will become into this:

[image]

As you can see there everything is fine but the FontAwesome icon. Is there any way to refresh the button so the changes takes effect? Or do you know any other way to achieve this?

Comment: could you please add response text too ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra done, up on the OP

Comment: Can you show the HTML once it's rendered in the browser? I don't see that the script used for generating the rows is relevant to the question; unless I'm missing something I think all we'd need to see is: the html (that you want to modify/operate on), the ajax script and event-handler that initiates and processes the call to the back end and the response text.

Comment: @DavidThomas the last snippet of HTML code is how the rendered code looks like. I just add the `$.each` loop but I will edit the OP and remove what is non necessary and add what you're asking me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to change the text like you are doing now, use `.html()` instead and replace only necessary strings, this way you maintain the structure of the button's content.

Try this:

```
// this one is for the Archive action
$.each(response, function (index, value) {
    var this_row_tr = $('input[data-form=' + value.row_id + ']').closest('tr');
    var archiveToUnarchive = this_row_tr.find('.btn[class*="archive"]');
    if (value.status === true) {
        this_row_tr.addClass('info');
        archiveToUnarchive.toggleClass('archive-form unarchive-form')
                .html(archiveToUnarchive.html()
                .replace('Archive', 'Unarchive')
                .replace('fa-arrow-circle-down', 'fa-arrow-circle-up'));
    } else if (value.status === false) {
        this_row_tr.addClass('error');
        all_deleted = false;
    }
});

// this one is for the Unarchive action
$.each(response, function (index, value) {
    var this_row_tr = $('input[data-form=' + value.row_id + ']').closest('tr');
    var unarchiveToArchive = this_row_tr.find('.btn[class*="archive"]');

    if (value.status === true) {
        unarchiveToArchive.toggleClass('archive-form unarchive-form')
                .html(unarchiveToArchive.html()
                .replace('Unarchive', 'Archive')
                .replace('fa-arrow-circle-up', 'fa-arrow-circle-down'));
        this_row_tr.removeClassName('info');
    } else if (value.status === false) {
        this_row_tr.addClass('error');
        all_deleted = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: @ReynierPM, This is now roking if I click again on same button like Archieve to UnArchieve and then again from Archieve to UnArchieve.

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra; since the OP has two `$.each` to separate the scenarios (unarchiveToArchive andn archiveToUnarchive) then there should be no problem. If the OP would want to use only one `$.each`, then a little more logic should be added as to what replaces what according to the current state of the button, but the relevant part in this case, what the OP said to be stuck with was the fact that he/she was using `.text()` instead of `.html()` and `.replace()`, which was messing up the result inside the button

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra. To simulate the behaviour of the button without the ajax call try:`$(document).on('click', 'button.archive-form', function() {$(this).toggleClass('archive-form unarchive-form').html($(this).html().replace('Archive', 'Unarchive').replace('fa-arrow-circle-down', 'fa-arrow-circle-up'));});` and `<button class="btn archive-form" data-form="12518"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Archive</button>` HIH

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you only need the functionality for Archieve and UnArchieve,

Could you please try the following script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".unarchive-form").click(unArchieveToArchieve);
    $(".archive-form").click(archieveUnArchieve);

    function unArchieveToArchieve(){
        var btn = $(this);
        var rowId = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".to-upload").attr("data-form");

        var response = [{"row_id":rowId,"status" :true}];

        $.each(response, function (index, value) {
            var this_row_tr = $('input[data-form=' + value.row_id + ']').closest('tr');

            if (value.status === true) {
                this_row_tr.attr('class','');
                $(btn).text("Archieve");
                $(btn).removeClass("unarchive-form");
                $(btn).addClass("archive-form");
                $(btn).click(archieveUnArchieve)
            } else if (value.status === false) {
                this_row_tr.attr('class','error');
                all_deleted = false;
            }
        });
    }
    function archieveUnArchieve(){

        var btn = $(this);
        var rowId = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".to-upload").attr("data-form");

        var response = [{"row_id":rowId,"status" :true}];

        $.each(response, function (index, value) {
            var this_row_tr = $('input[data-form=' + value.row_id + ']').closest('tr');

            if (value.status === true) {
                this_row_tr.attr('class','info');
                $(btn).text("Unarchive");
                $(btn).removeClass("archive-form");
                $(btn).addClass("unarchive-form");
                $(btn).click(unArchieveToArchieve)
            } else if (value.status === false) {
                this_row_tr.attr('class' , 'error');
                all_deleted = false;
            }
        });

    }

});
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Let me know if you need further details.